# method not returns a value bit an alert box show value react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a method that calculates a bpm value but this function not returning the value. i tried to add an alert box , and the alert box did show value! i also tried to return just a number and it didn't work. i think is it a logic problem or i don't write the return as needed.
im working with react.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import detect from 'bpm-detective';


class SongsList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isPlay: false,
        SongId: this.props.songs.id,
        isPlayAll: this.props.playAll,
        bpm: 3

    };

    this.toggleSong = this.toggleSong.bind(this);
    this.bpmCalculator = this.bpmCalculator.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.setBpm = this.setBpm.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.bpmCalculator(this.props.songs.source, this.setBpm)
}

bpmCalculator(songSrc, workWithMahBPM) {
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext;
    const locSrc = '/audio/';
    const src = locSrc + songSrc;
    let context = new AudioContext();
    let tempBpm = "";

    // Fetch some audio file
    fetch(src)
    // Get response as ArrayBuffer
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => {
            // Decode audio into an AudioBuffer
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.decodeAudioData(buffer, resolve, reject);
            });
        })
        // Run detection
        .then(buffer => {
                try {
                    tempBpm  = detect(buffer);
                    workWithMahBPM(tempBpm);
                    alert(`${ tempBpm }`);

                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            }
        );
}

setBpm(calculatedBPM) {
    this.setState({ bpm: calculatedBPM })
}


componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.playAll !== this.props.playAll) {
        this.setState({
            isPlayAll: nextProps.playAll,
            isPlay: nextProps.playAll
        });
    }
}


toggleSong() {
    if (this.state.isPlay) {
        document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.state.SongId).pause();
        this.setState({
            isPlay: false
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.state.SongId).play();
        this.setState({
            isPlay: true
        });
    }
}

render() {
    /*        // console.log(this.props);
            let songListJSX = this.props.songs.map((song)=>{
                let classList = "";
                if(this.props.currentSongId === song.id){
                    classList += " song-card__playing"
                }*/

    var { bpm } = this.state.bpm;
    let playBtn = '\u25BA';
    if (this.state.isPlay) {
        playBtn = '\u258C\u258C';
    }


    /*        if(this.state.isPlayAll)
            {
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.state.SongId).play();
                this.setState({
                    isPlay: true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.state.SongId).stop();
                this.setState({
                    isPlay: false
                });
            }*/

    return (

        <div className="player">
            <audio id={"currentAudio" + this.props.songs.id} src={"/audio/" + this.props.songs.source}/>
            <span className="orange-button" onClick={() => {
                {
                    this.toggleSong(this.props.songs.id)
                }
            }}> {playBtn}  </span>
            <div className="track-info">
                <h2 className="track-title">{this.props.songs.title}</h2>
                <h3 className="track-user">{this.props.songs.artist}</h3>
                <h3><span>{bpm}</span></h3>

            </div>


        </div>

    );
}


/*               <div className={ "song-card" + classList } key={ song.id }>
                   <audio id={"currentAudio" + song.id} src={ "/audio/" + song.source } onDurationChange={ this.setCurrentSongDuration } onTimeUpdate={ this.setCurrentSongTime }></audio>
                   <span className="play-btn" onClick={ ()=>{ this.props.btnHandler(song.id) } }> &#9658; </span>
                   <img className="song-card__img" src={ song.albumCover } alt="" />
                   <div className="song-card__title">
                       <Link to={"/" + song.id} onClick={ ()=>{ this.props.linkHandler(song.id) } }>
                           <h2> { song.title } </h2>
                       </Link>
                   </div>
               </div>
           );
       });*/

/*        return (
            <div className="playlist">
                <div className="playlist__title">
                    <h1> Featured Playlist: Funky Beats </h1>
                </div>
                <div className="playlist__content">
                    { songListJSX }
                </div>
            </div>
        )*/
```

}

export default SongsList;

Comment: The return you're writing there returns from the callback function passed to `.then(callback)`

Comment: try `return tempBpm` after `.then();`

Comment: @LiadLevy you’ve got two solid answers below. Would you mind accepting one? It’s customary to accept an answer that works for you and upvote it.

Comment: @twils0 it still now working

Comment: What's happening? Are you getting an error? For my answer, are you able to use async functions and await? If you can't, you will need to use Levitator's answer.

Comment: if i put an alert before the return i get the number, but the number doesn't appear in the html page.
<h3><span>{bpm}</span></h3>
i get no errors!!
how can i know if i can use async functions and await?
thanks, liad.

Comment: I would say: if you have to ask if you can use async and await, you may want to just avoid using them right now. You would need to make sure your babel/webpack configs are setup correct (if you're using webpack). Hopefully, Levitator's answer can get you a bit closer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return value from asynchronous function. If you want to work with value that appears inside the asynchronous function, then you should pass some callback function that will receive calculated result as a parameter.

```
bpmCalculator(songSrc, workWithMahBPM) {
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext;
    const locSrc = '/audio/';
    const src = locSrc + songSrc;
    let context = new AudioContext();
    let tempBpm = "";

    // Fetch some audio file
    fetch(src)
    // Get response as ArrayBuffer
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => {
            // Decode audio into an AudioBuffer
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.decodeAudioData(buffer, resolve, reject);
            });
        })
        // Run detection
        .then(buffer => {
                try {
                    tempBpm  = detect(buffer);
                    workWithMahBPM(tempBpm)
                    /*alert(`${ tempBpm }`);*/

                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            }
        );
}

handleBPM(calculatedBPM) {
    // do whatever with your BPM
}

/* SOMEWHERE IN THE CODE */
bpmCalculator("myawesometrack.ogg", handleBPM)
```

---

**UPDATE**
In your case the component of the song can be implemented like this^

```
export default class MyAvesomeTrackView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            bpm: undefined
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.bpmCalculator(this.props.songSrc, this.setBpm)
    }

    bpmCalculator(songSrc, workWithMahBPM) {
        const AudioContext = window.AudioContext;
        const locSrc = '/audio/';
        const src = locSrc + songSrc;
        let context = new AudioContext();
        let tempBpm = "";

        // Fetch some audio file
        fetch(src)
        // Get response as ArrayBuffer
            .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
            .then(buffer => {
                // Decode audio into an AudioBuffer
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    context.decodeAudioData(buffer, resolve, reject);
                });
            })
            // Run detection
            .then(buffer => {
                    try {
                        tempBpm  = detect(buffer);
                        workWithMahBPM(tempBpm)
                        /*alert(`${ tempBpm }`);*/

                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    setBpm(calculatedBPM) {
        this.setState({ bpm: calculatedBPM })
    }

    render() {
        var { songSrc } = this.props
        var { bpm } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="my-awesome-track">
                <div>Song src: {songSrc}</div>
                {/* somewhere inside the markup */}
                <span>{bpm || "Calculating..."}</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to add the calculated value in a render function:
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="title-bar">
                    <img className="logo" src="/Cloud.png" alt=""/>
                    <h1> Musico - Looper </h1>
                    <h2>{this.bpmCalculator("upstep.mp3")}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
)}

how can i do that?

Comment: @LiadLevy hmm, then you have a ```this.state```, where you can store all you asynchronous data with ```this.setState({ yourField: yourData })```. I will update my answer in this context as soon as possible

Comment: it is still not working.
i'm updating the code that you will see all component.

Comment: @LiadLevy man, instead of ```var { bpm } = this.state.bpm``` you should write ```var { bpm } = this.state```, I suppose)